# How to send hyperlinks in an SMS message using Java

Tags: javascript, java

I am new to sending sms messages using java. Messages are sent well but hyperlinks are not clickable in android mobile.

Example sms:

Hi chandru, Please click this url and reset your password http://localhost:8080/tosAngularJs/rpd?tid=xsRt+CTIadnAcL7NHiB2Cf+eHVWfOZaf

Here, the url is clickable but its does not show in the SMS.

Comment: hey, i am also working on sms sending using java,how you have done this can you help me out, i have zero knowledge in this

Answer (score 0):

I found problem, Just remove port number from url.

Example:
 http://www.stackoverflow.com/rpd?tid=xsRt+CTIadnAcL7NHiB2Cf+eHVWfOZaf